# Attempting to print from method within class

Tags: class

I'm still relatively new to Python and some concepts so you'll have to bear with me.

I am trying to create an animal (in this case a horse), and generate some attributes to it automatically. Here I am attempting to generate and apply the height function to the class using my get_heights method.  I am not getting any errors, however it is not printing out the generated numbers that it does when I define it as an independent function. (Outside of a class).

I added parentheses to `Horse_heights.get_heights` call, but then I get a type error saying `get_heights() takes exactly 3 arguments <1 given>`. All help is appreciated, apologies if I'm missing some fundamental aspect here.

```
import random

 class Horse(object):
     def __init__(self, horse_name):
         self.horse_name = horse_name

    def get_heights(self, starting_height, max_height):
        for sh in range(15):
            sh1 = random.randint(14, 15)
            sh3 = str(sh1)
            self.sh3 = starting_height
        print starting_height

        for mh in range(3):
            mh1 = random.randint(1,2)
            mh2 = mh1 + sh1
            mh3 = str(mh2)
            self.mh3 = max_height
        print max_height


 Horse_Heights = Horse("Secretariat")
 Horse_Heights.get_heights
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, function get_height takes 3 arguments:

```
def get_heights(self, starting_height, max_height)
```

So when you call this function insert argments:

```
import random

class Horse(object):
    def __init__(self, horse_name):
         self.horse_name = horse_name

    def get_heights(self, starting_height, max_height):
        for sh in range(15):
            sh1 = random.randint(14, 15)
            sh3 = str(sh1)
            self.sh3 = starting_height
        print starting_height

        for mh in range(3):
            mh1 = random.randint(1,2)
            mh2 = mh1 + sh1
            mh3 = str(mh2)
            self.mh3 = max_height
        print max_height


Horse_Heights = Horse("Secretariat")
Horse_Heights.get_heights(1,15)
```

Comment: Well, yes but then it does not use the random integers generated to determine the height. I guess I will have to define those outside of the class beforehand, then apply them to it.